# Error while adding a watermark to mp4 with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

I try to watermark an mp4 file with ffmpeg and the following command :

```
ffmpeg -i originalvideo.mp4 -vf « movie=watermark.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=0:0:1 [out]«  watermarkedvideo.mp4
```

after some process I get this error :

```
[NULL @ 0x168f5e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[wm]'
[wm]: Invalid argument
[in][wm]: command not found
```

Edit:
Finally command wasnt correct, this one work.

```
ffmpeg -i originalvideo.mp4 -vf "movie=wartermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-3:main_h-overlay_h-3 [out]" outputvideo.mp4
```

Comment: The few examples I see use `[watermark]`

Comment: Why do use these bizarre quotation marks? Also, are they really closed? I see two of these «. I think that's the problem. That is also why you get `command not found` errors. Check http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: Yes i change for that one : "ffmpeg -i originalvideo.mp4 -vf "movie=wartermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-3:main_h-overlay_h-3 [out]" outputvideo.mp4 ", now i have some problem with the buffer..

Comment: Please update your question with your current ffmpeg command and the complete console output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use. It doesn't use ffmpeg (which is deprecated), but rather avconv, a part of the **libav-tools** package .

Here is what I used to add a watermark:

```
avconv -i input.mpg -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark];[in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]" -c:v mpeg2video -c:a copy output2.mpg
```

Here are a few useful links:

[Teal Scientific discussing avconv](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906214906/http://tealscientific.com/blog/?p=1961)

[StackExchange Discussion on using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155246/ffmpeg-avfilter-overlay-watermark-programmatically)

[Youtube video of avconv](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89uH9r2BSMs)

Comment: The "deprecated" message is misleading as many users assume it means the FFmpeg project and not libav's version of `ffmpeg`: [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)